# We are not able to fetch the records from the Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to poll data from a specific topic but I didn't receive any records. I am using below code snippet:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
```

Note: I am subscribing to the specific topic and partition also.

Comment: Maybe that partition just doesn't have any new messages?

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon, I have seen through the cmd there are new messages